# running a perl script from bash script with variable arguments

Tags: bash, perl

Hi I'm trying to write a simple script that takes 2 arguments and runs a perl script with the provided input

```
agents=$1
group=$2
while read agent
do
perl perlscript.pl perlconfig.conf --update_agent $agent group_name $group  
done < $agents
```

when I run this perl script on the command line with hand typed variables it works fine. However when running the script I get an error from the perl script that the update_agent command is expecting 3 arguments but is given 4. I can't seem to figure out where the 4th variable is coming from.  Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Since you didn't show us the Perl code which is complaining, we can't answer your question.

Comment: I can already count 5 arguments. More if `$agent` or `$group` have spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least,

```
perl perlscript.pl perlconfig.conf --update_agent $agent group_name $group
```

should be

```
perl perlscript.pl perlconfig.conf --update_agent "$agent" group_name "$group"
```

Is the only problem? No idea. You've given too little to work from.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to have worked although now I'm having trouble trimming the variable that I'm reading in i've tried `$agent=$(echo "$agent" |tr -d '\n')` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: changing the code to `agent=$(echo $agent | tr -d '\r')` I don't really understand the difference between `\n` and `\r` but my problem is fixed thank you very much!

Comment: They are different characters. Windows text files have CR LF (\r\n) for line endings, while unix text files have LF for line endings. As such, you could also fix the file by passing its file name to `dos2unix`.